# Hibernate map subclass ignoring parent

Tags: java, hibernate

I'd like to map lots of subclasses with a common parent class : B extends A, C extends A,... but the database doesn't care A. And B and C have nothing in common (no Id, no reference...).

```
public class A {
    @Id
    @Column(name="id")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name="reference", nullable=false)
    private String reference;

}
```

Is it possible to do this without adding @Entity ?

**SOLUTION**

```
@MappedSuperclass
public class A {
    @Id
    @Column(name="id")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name="reference", nullable=false)
    private String reference;

}

@Entity
@Table(name="B")
public class B extends A {
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`@MappedSuperclass`](http://www.objectdb.com/api/java/jpa/MappedSuperclass) on class `A`:

> Designates a class whose mapping information is applied to the entities that inherit from it. A mapped superclass has no separate table defined for it.